# SSAS 2005, Excel 2007, Ragged Hierarchy

Tags: excel, ssas, bids

I am trying to update a SSAS 2005 cube adding a ragged hierarchy (it has a few levels that contain members that should be hidden if the member name is the same as the parent).

From various sources I have read that I need to use MDX Comparability=2 within the connection string to see the HideMemberIf property. I have read so many opinions on this bug / problem that I have confused myself.

Does anyone have a solution for ragged hierarchies that has worked in a production environment with excel 2007?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ragged hierarchies should work in Excel provided that you have the repeating or null members from the leaf up and not in the intermediate levels.

So the following ragged hierarchy would not work

```
Parent 1 -> Parent 1 -> Child 1
```

...as you would be attempting to hide a level in the middle of the hierarchy

But the same ragged hierarchy could also be represented as

```
Parent 1 -> Child 1 -> Child 1
```

Should work as you are hiding repeating members below a certain point.